# Changing permalink won't redirect to new version of page

Tags: permalinks, redirect

I created a new version of a Page. I changed the permalink of the previous (deprecated) version. I then changed the permalink of the new version to the original permalink.

Unfortunately, Wordpress continues to redirect to the deprecated version. I went so far as to trash the deprecated Page and now the new version redirects to a 404.

I then went to PHPMyAdmin and deleted a PostMeta on the old page '_wp_old_slug' and that did absolutely nothing.

What is best practice for handling this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Browsers are pretty bad about hard-caching redirects. I would first use an HTTP header checker (there are many free ones online, just search) to verify the URL you want really is still redirecting. If it gives you a 200, then it's your browser, and dumping the whole cache should help.

If you still see it redirecting in the header checker, it's likely there's some level of caching at play. Deleting the postmeta was the right thing to do, but if any plugin or your host have caching enabled, that could also be keeping the redirect in place overly long. Purging varies by provider.